# Find a (partial) list of matrix unity roots

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am looking for a way to build a list of matrix square roots of 1 and -1.
Only interested in dimensions 2 to 4, and I don't even need a complete set, just a practical usable one (meaning I could stop the loop at some point).
Here's my (very) inefficient solution

```
def racines(n, dim, field='real'):
    if field == 'real':
        unites = [1, 0, -1]
    elif field == 'complex':
        unites = [1, 0, -1, 1j, -1j]
    if dim == 2:
        liste = [np.array([[a,b], [c,d]]) for a in unites
                 for b in unites for c in unites 
                 for d in unites]
    elif dim == 3:
        liste = [np.array([[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]])
                 for a in unites for b in unites for c in unites 
                 for d in unites for e in unites for f in unites
                 for g in unites for h in unites for i in unites]
    elif dim == 4:
        liste = [np.array([[a,b,c,d], [e,f,g,h], [i,j,k,l], [m,o,p,q]])
                 for a in unites for b in unites for c in unites for d in unites
                 for e in unites for f in unites for g in unites for h in unites
                 for i in unites for j in unites for k in unites for l in unites
                 for m in unites for o in unites for p in unites for q in unites]
    liste = [m for m in liste if np.linalg.det(m) != 0]
    liste = [m for m in liste if np.array_equal(np.matmul(m, m), np.identity(dim, dtype='int')*n)]
return(liste)
```

Works well until 4d where of course it becomes too much to handle...
How to make it faster ?

Comment: Seriously: 16 nested loops? In the complex case, this require `5**16 = 152_587_890_625` iterations... Moreover, this will create a list with the same amount of CPython Numpy objects with a size of at least 256 byte each. Do you have a computer with at least 36_379 GiB of memory? Besides the memory usage, the amount of computation is far too big. The problem is the *algorithm* : using a brute-force strategy is not a good idea. You need to check for an *analytical solution* and this involves advanced math, not programming. It is probably better to ask this on https://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I knew this is nuts, that's why I asked for help^^
Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively. For exemple if I want the lists of n numbers between 0 and 4 you could use

```py
def get_lists(size, max_it, accumulator = [], lists = []):
    if size ==0:
        lists.append(accumulator)
    else:
        for i in range(5):
            if len(lists) == max_it:
                break
            l = accumulator.copy()
            l.append(i)
            get_lists(size-1,max_it, l, lists)

            
def lists(size,max_it=-1):
    l = []  
    get_lists(size,max_it, [], l)
    return l        
print(lists(3,10))
```

with max_it the amount of different list you want (set to -1 if you want them all)

Comment: Thanks, this works pretty well !
Still complicated for the complex 4d case, but I'll use 2x2 real/complex matrices instead of the elements of the 2x2 roots and that'll do nicely.

Comment: For what it's worth, 4d real values takes 6min with recursive while 9min with brute-force.
I'm not trying with complex numbers ^^

Comment: If you don't need them all you can just stop the program before the end

Answer (score 0):

For those who would need it, here's what did the trick.
Still not pretty, but it works a lot faster in 4d

```
def racines(n, dim, field='real'):
    unites = [1, 0, -1]
    if field == 'complex':
        unites += [1j, -1j]
    elif field != 'real':
        print('Unknown field !')
        return([])
    if dim == 2:
        liste = [np.array([[a,b], [c,d]]) for a in unites
                 for b in unites for c in unites 
                 for d in unites]
    elif dim == 3:
        liste = [np.array([[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]])
                 for a in unites for b in unites for c in unites 
                 for d in unites for e in unites for f in unites
                 for g in unites for h in unites for i in unites]
    elif dim == 4:
        roots_2d = racines(n, 2, field=field)
        neg_roots_2d = racines(-n, 2, field=field)
        other = [np.identity(2, dtype='int'), np.identity(2, dtype='int')*-1, np.zeros([2,2], dtype='int')]
        unites = roots_2d + neg_roots_2d + other
        liste = [np.hstack([np.vstack([a,b]), np.vstack([c,d])])
                 for a in unites for b in unites for c in unites for d in unites]
    else:
        print('No can do !')
        return([])
    liste = [m for m in liste if np.linalg.det(m) != 0]
    liste = [m for m in liste if np.array_equal(np.matmul(m, m), np.identity(dim, dtype='int')*n)]
    return(liste)
# res = racines(1, 4, field='real') # 2.43s
# res = racines(1, 4, field='complex') # 2min 18s
```